# In PHP, get an array value when you know another value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can't find any solution to this problem, all my attempts failed, so I need your help please.

I have to define the different teams that will confront one another in a soccer tournament. I know the 4 groups of teams of the tournament and which games should be played on every day, but I don't manage to display the tournament program thanks to this information.

I have 2 arrays:

-the tournament program (defined by the ranking of each team in each group, there are 2 matches per day in each of the 4 groups):

```
$tournament = array(
    "day1" => array(1=> array("team1", "team2"), 2=> array("team3", "team4")),
    "day2" => array(1=> array("team3", "team1"), 2=> array("team4", "team2")),
    "day3" => array(1=> array("team1", "team4"), 2=> array("team2", "team3")),
    "day4" => array(1=> array("team2", "team1"), 2=> array("team4", "team3")),
    "day5" => array(1=> array("team1", "team3"), 2=> array("team2", "team4")),
    "day6" => array(1=> array("team4", "team1"), 2=> array("team3", "team2"))
);
```

-the groups details:

```
$users_group = array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [team] => Superteam1 [rank] => 1 [group] => A ) 
    [1] => Array ( [team] => Superteam2 [rank] => 2 [group] => A ) 
    [2] => Array ( [team] => Superteam3 [rank] => 3 [group] => A ) 
    [3] => Array ( [team] => Superteam4 [rank] => 4 [group] => A ) 
    [4] => Array ( [team] => Superteam5 [rank] => 1 [group] => B ) 
    [5] => Array ( [team] => Superteam6 [rank] => 2 [group] => B ) 
    [6] => Array ( [team] => Superteam7 [rank] => 3 [group] => B ) 
    [7] => Array ( [team] => Superteam8 [rank] => 4 [group] => B ) 
    [8] => Array ( [team] => Superteam9 [rank] => 1 [group] => C ) 
    [9] => Array ( [team] => Superteam10 [rank] => 2 [group] => C ) 
    [10] => Array ( [team] => Superteam11 [rank] => 3 [group] => C ) 
    [11] => Array ( [team] => Superteam12 [rank] => 4 [group] => C ) 
    [12] => Array ( [team] => Superteam13 [rank] => 1 [group] => D ) 
    [13] => Array ( [team] => Superteam14 [rank] => 2 [group] => D ) 
    [14] => Array ( [team] => Superteam15 [rank] => 3 [group] => D ) 
    [15] => Array ( [team] => Superteam16 [rank] => 4 [group] => D ) 
)
```

I would like, for each day of the tournament, to display both of the matches that will be played. However what I tried does not work, I can only get the first team of the first game (N.B. the first while loop is used to get the 6 days of tournament from my db):

```
$i=1;
while($i<7){
    echo '<div>Day '.$i.'</div>';

    $max = count( $users_group ); 
    for( $l = 0; $l < $max; $l++ ){
        if($users_group[$l]['rang']==substr($tournament["day".$i][1][0],-1)){
          echo $users_group[$l]['team']; 
        }
        if($users_group[$l]['rang']==substr($tournament["day".$i][1][1],-1)){
          echo ' VS '.$users_group[$l]['team'] . '<br />'; 
        }

        if($users_group[$l]['rang']==substr($tournament["day".$i][2][0],-1)){
          echo $users_group[$l]['team']; 
        }
        if($users_group[$l]['rang']==substr($tournament["day".$i][2][1],-1)){
          echo ' VS '.$users_group[$l]['team'] . '<br />'; 
        }


    }
    $i++;
}
```

I'd like to show something like:

```
Day 1

Superteam1 VS Superteam2
Superteam3 VS Superteam4

Superteam5 VS Superteam6
Superteam7 VS Superteam8

Superteam9 VS Superteam10
Superteam11 VS Superteam12

Superteam13 VS Superteam14
Superteam15 VS Superteam16


Day 2

Superteam3 VS Superteam1
Superteam4 VS SUperteam2

etc
.
.
.
```

I tried to make a function to avoid only getting the first value of `$users_group[$l]['team']` every time but I couldn't make it work.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Did you set up these data structures? You've made life difficult by adding unnecessary text to the array values in `$tournament`. It would be much easier just to have the numbers of the teams that will be playing each other. The answer you've posted also bears no resemblance to the data provided -- there is no day 8 in the input array.

Comment: As I said, the day 4 and day 8 are coming from a while loop which provide info from a table of my db. This is not the point. Also, I did not include all my code, but all the datas that I get in my arrays are useful for further information to display. Thank you for your answer anyway

Comment: It is extremely helpful if you provide the expected output--if you provide output that cannot be correlated with the input, it is just confusing. Neither your `while` loop or `$tournament` has any information about day 8, so putting that down as expected output is misleading. It would be very helpful if you could provide more code as your question could be easily answered with a different data structure, but if you are stuck on the data structures you already have, a workaround would have to be devised.

Comment: Okay, I edited my code so that the day isn't a problem anymore and neither my while loop, even though I still don't understand why it was so disturbing as I had explained it. Again, this is absolutely not a problem in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the job. I've created new data structures to make it easier to access the data about groups, teams, days, and so on. I've put comments and explanations in the code, but please ask if you don't understand what it is doing.

```
<?php

$tournament = array(
    "day1" => array(1=> array("team1", "team2"), 2=> array("team3", "team4")),
    "day2" => array(1=> array("team3", "team1"), 2=> array("team4", "team2")),
    "day3" => array(1=> array("team1", "team4"), 2=> array("team2", "team3")),
    "day4" => array(1=> array("team2", "team1"), 2=> array("team4", "team3")),
    "day5" => array(1=> array("team1", "team3"), 2=> array("team2", "team4")),
    "day6" => array(1=> array("team4", "team1"), 2=> array("team3", "team2"))
);


$users_group = array (
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam1', 'rank' => 1, 'group' => 'A' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam2', 'rank' => 2, 'group' => 'A' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam3', 'rank' => 3, 'group' => 'A' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam4', 'rank' => 4, 'group' => 'A' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam5', 'rank' => 1, 'group' => 'B' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam6', 'rank' => 2, 'group' => 'B' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam7', 'rank' => 3, 'group' => 'B' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam8', 'rank' => 4, 'group' => 'B' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam9', 'rank' => 1, 'group' => 'C' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam10', 'rank' => 2, 'group' => 'C' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam11', 'rank' => 3, 'group' => 'C' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam12', 'rank' => 4, 'group' => 'C' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam13', 'rank' => 1, 'group' => 'D' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam14', 'rank' => 2, 'group' => 'D' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam15', 'rank' => 3, 'group' => 'D' ),
    array( 'team' => 'Superteam16', 'rank' => 4, 'group' => 'D' ),
);

# this function is used by array_map to remove "team" from the $tournament data struct.
$func = function($value) {
    $value = str_replace("team", "", $value);
    return $value;
};

# redo the tournament array to remove all the "day" and "team" strings
foreach ($tournament as $day => $val) {
    $new_day = str_replace("day", "", $day);
    foreach ($val as $m => $t) {
        # this removes "team" from the values
        $days[$new_day][$m] = array_map( $func, $t );
    }
}

# turn the users_group array into a multidimension array in the form
# $ranked_ug = [ group ][ rank ] = team
$ranked_ug = array();
foreach( $users_group as $u => $data ){
    $ranked_ug[ $data['group'] ][ $data['rank'] ] = $data['team'];
}

# this is used to get data about the team from $ranked_ug
function getKey( $t_data ) {
    return function ( $value ) use ($t_data) {
        return $t_data[$value];
    };
}

# for each day...
foreach ($days as $d => $d_data) {
    echo "<h2>Day $d</h2>\n";
    # iterate through each group
    foreach ($ranked_ug as $g => $g_data) {
        echo "<h3>Group $g Matches</h3>\n";
        # look at each match
        foreach ($d_data as $match_no => $teams) {
            echo "<p>Match $match_no<br>\n";
            # $teams contains the numbers of the teams playing
            # pull the team name from $ranked_ug using $ranked_ug[$g][ rank ]
            # this line uses implode to join the team names with "vs"
            # and array_map to automatically get the team name from $ranked_ug
            echo implode(" vs ",
                array_map( getKey( $ranked_ug[$g] ), $teams ) ) . "</p>\n";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output for groups A and B for the first three days:

```
<h2>Day 1</h2>
<h3>Group A Matches</h3>
<p>Match 1<br>
Superteam1 vs Superteam2</p>
<p>Match 2<br>
Superteam3 vs Superteam4</p>

<h3>Group B Matches</h3>
<p>Match 1<br>
Superteam5 vs Superteam6</p>
<p>Match 2<br>
Superteam7 vs Superteam8</p>


<h2>Day 2</h2>
<h3>Group A Matches</h3>
<p>Match 1<br>
Superteam3 vs Superteam1</p>
<p>Match 2<br>
Superteam4 vs Superteam2</p>

<h3>Group B Matches</h3>
<p>Match 1<br>
Superteam7 vs Superteam5</p>
<p>Match 2<br>
Superteam8 vs Superteam6</p>


<h2>Day 3</h2>
<h3>Group A Matches</h3>
<p>Match 1<br>
Superteam1 vs Superteam4</p>
<p>Match 2<br>
Superteam2 vs Superteam3</p>

<h3>Group B Matches</h3>
<p>Match 1<br>
Superteam5 vs Superteam8</p>
<p>Match 2<br>
Superteam6 vs Superteam7</p>
```

Comment: Thank you i alarmed alien I'm gonna try that!

Comment: That didn't work as expected I'm sorry here's what I get with your code:

Day day1

Group A Matches

Match 1
vs

Match 2
vs

Group B Matches

Match 1
vs

Match 2
vs 

The same matches for every day.

Comment: I've copied in the data structures that I used as it sounds like an issue extracting the information from the arrays. You should be able to copy and paste the script above into a file and run it as-is to create the results. If it doesn't work, would you tell me what version of PHP you're using?

Comment: I'm trying something else with just a part of your code, I will let you know when I make it work :)
Thank you
PS : my PHP version is 5.4.30